# Link tag to bower components when not web accessible

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gulp, bower, assets

I have a Rails app that has the Asset Pipeline disabled. I am using Gulp to compile and serve my CSS and JS etc. In `/vendor/assets` I have a bower-components directory. I want to add `<link>` tags to my `application.html.erb` file to some .css files that are inside some components I have installed from Bower. Is there some sort of helper I could write that I could use to allow files in the `bower-components` directory to be referenced from my `application.html.erb` file or would the `bower-components` directory have to be placed inside `/public/assets`?

UPDATE (Answer to @ted-whitehead):

I looked at using that and the problem is that if I use main bower files then it will compile, concatenate and move the files listed as being main into their respective places but other files referenced by those main ones don't get moved. Say they were images, the paths to those files now gets broken. Look at the bower.json file of `flag-icon-css`: `{

```
  "name": "flag-icon-css",
  "main": [
    "css/flag-icon.min.css",
    "less/flag-icon.less",
    "sass/_flag-icon.scss"
  ],
  "ignore": [
      "**/.*",
      "assets",
      "Gruntfile.coffee",
      "index.html",
      "LICENSE",
      "package.json"
  ]
}
```

That's all well and good but there is an SVG file for each country and the references to those gets broken. I know the plugin allows you to override and add missing main files but it's a bit over the top to have to add all the svg files for every country! See what I mean?

Comment: Have a look at these 1) https://blog.bugsnag.com/replacing-the-rails-asset-pipeline-with-gulp/ 2) https://github.com/vigetlabs/gulp-rails-pipeline

Comment: I've seen the second link before but not the first one. It doesn;t really help with bower components though. I know it mentions Rails-Assets but I don;t really want them brought in via gems. I would prefer using Bower as normal and being able to link to the assets from within my layout files. Is there a solution for this?

Comment: I’ve used gulp to output the compiled JS to the app/assets folder in the past, which you could then reference. If you just want to copy Bower assets to app/assets you could use https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-main-bower-files

Comment: Read my update in my OP

Comment: @ted-whitehead  Anymore thoughts on this? Thankyou.